# How do i get mysql rank to go in the proper diretion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Helllo.

I am writing a query to do a couple things. Users are assigned a team, each user has points, I am grouping users by their team name and tallying their points. I also assign a rank.

It all works fine but the Ranking give a rank of 1 to the lowest score instead of the highest score. This is my query

```
SELECT users.teamname as Team, users.points AS Score, COUNT(users.points) AS Members, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank
FROM users,(SELECT @curRank := 0) r
WHERE !(teamname is null)
GROUP BY `teamname`
ORDER BY Score
```

I think i have to nest something but I have never done something like that before.

Comment: Could you just `ORDER BY Score DESC` - and would the ranking then be correct?

Comment: I think you also want to SUM(points) not COUNT(points).

Comment: @scrowler When i do `ORDER BY Score DESC` the rank is then in reverse.

Comment: Add rank in PHP using a simple $i++ iterator, jus use your score in SQL to sort correctly but ignore the returned number

Comment: @user1336827 the COUNT is counting the number of people/scores contributing to the overall team score.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be:

```
ORDER BY Score
```

since you didn't specify a direction, it's ascending.  In other words, the lowest value is at the top.  To put the highest value at the top do this:

```
ORDER BY Score desc
```

or it might be something else.

Comment: I tried `ORDER BY Score DESC` and it does put the score in the proper order but then the rank ends up being backwards.